# Storing token frequencies in elasticsearch, instead of storing text

Tags: python, elasticsearch, tokenize, word-frequency

From my understanding from reading the documents, how elasticsearch works is that it counts term frequency * indiverse term frequency. It converts text to some sort of term frequency dictionary that also includes the indices of locations where these terms are most frequent.

What I'm trying to do is not store text, but term frequencies for each row of data. The search works fine when I simply upload the full text, but it will not work well in a full scale solution with 10+mil pages of text. Would it not be more effective to only store term frequencies if the text content otherwise is irrelevant?

edit: the anonymity of the data is also relevant and therefore I would not want full sentences and paragraphs stored externally.

Comment: Anyone? This is critical for my application.

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes, you could implement a termvector in the text field for the term frequencies. Please read the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html#docs-termvectors).
Then you could use the bulk query for termvector that is mtermvector- [doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-termvectors.html), and [python api doc](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=mtermvector#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.mtermvectors).  It works with a list of ids. For example, If you have a list of all the ids of your documents that match "sky" you could proceed in that way:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

index = "abc"
my_doc_type ="your_doc_type"
ids = []

result = es.search(index="abc", doc_type= my_doc_type body={"query": {"term": {"my_field":  "sky"}}})     

for res in in result['hits']['hits']:
    ids.append(res['ids'])




for doc in es.mtermvectors(index=index,doc_type=doc_type,body=dict(ids=ids,parameters=dict(term_statistics=True,field_statistics=True,fields=fields)))['docs']:                                                                                                                                                            
    fields = doc['term_vectors']  
    terms = field['terms']  
    tf = vec["term_freq"]
    df =  vec["doc_freq"]
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. What I ended up doing was disabling the _source (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) However, I'm not entirely sure if this "removes" the data? Also I don't know how to only disable the source on the one column, and not all of them.

Comment: I don't understand why you should disable the _source ? In this way you can't debug your queries. If you want to save space you should disable norms and put "index_options": "freqs" but pay attention ;-) Please read here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-disk-usage.html

Comment: Would disabling the source remove the data from the cluster? The data can not be stored in the cloud, I also don't need to see the data, but only search it so I can find the URLs associated with the texts. i.e. I want to search academic papers based on their content, but I have no need to ever retrieve the full text of the documents.